# Disharmonious vs inharmonious

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Inharmonious is defined as follows in [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inharmonious):

> inharmonious ADJECTIVE
>   Not forming or contributing to a pleasing whole; discordant.
>   ‘an inharmonious, negative state of mind’

Disharmonious is [defined](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disharmonious) as follows:

> Disharmonious ADJECTIVE
>   Lacking harmony

So as per the above definition, can I deduce the following:

> The statement **" She always makes situation disharmonious."** is a more suitable statement than **"She always makes situation inharmonious."**, because the situation can be said of lacking harmony; it can not always be said to be contributing to harmony, as **people in a situation are more involved in contributing as compared to the situation itself.**
>
> Similarly, "She is a disharmonious girl." is incorrect. It should rather be  **"She is an inharmonious girl."**

Comment: Well, the question is not just whether you *can* use the words in that way, but whether you *should*.  Both are difficult words to use elegantly, and your example sentences are like pounding the proverbial square peg into the round hole, determined to make them fit.  There are many other words that may work better:  *divisive, argumentative, discordant, disruptive, troublesome, contentious, unfriendly, etc.*  I actually prefer *not harmonious* to either of these two options.

Comment: You should say either, "She always makes situationS inharmonous," or "She always makes THE situation inharmonious."  "Disharmonious" usually refers to music, and is rarely used, in my experience. Also, thumbs up for Andrew's comment.  There are better choices.

Comment: @JiveDadson In the example sentences section for the word "disharmonious" at Oxford site, they have given  4 to 5 examples. In those examples, they have mentioned many contexts in which this word can be used. In none of those examples, the context related to music is mentioned.